# Android clean architecture and related entities

Tags: android, repository-pattern, clean-architecture

This is mostly a design question. I have 2 entities `Payment` and `User`, having a one-to-one relationship. The API call returns a list of `Payments` each `Payment` contains a `User`. The payments are displayed in a Recycler View, every row contains information from both the `Payment` and `User` entities. And to fetch them from the DB (using *Room*) I need to perform a join query that returns a combination of both entities:

```
@Query("SELECT payment.*, user.* FROM payment INNER JOIN user ON payment.user_id = user.userId")
fun findPaymentsAndUsers(): List<PaymentAndUser>

data class PaymentAndUser(
    @Embedded val payment: Payment,
    @Embedded val user: User)
```

My question is how can I create my repositories without breaking any of the *Clean Architecture* principles?

- Of course I cannot create 2 independent repositories and pass the data between them through the calling *UseCase* because they are already being returned together either in the API call or in the *Room DAO* query.
- The [single responsibility principle](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html) states that every repository should only handle its own entity, so I cannot create a `PaymentRepository` and handle everything from there.
- I also cannot group both entities into an *Aggregate* and create a repository than handles them both, because they are two independent Entities that can exist regardless of each other.

Every single *Android Clean Architecture* sample I found has one or two entities that are totally independent with no join queries or any sort of grouping, which is totally unrealistic in real life applications.

Is there any way this can be implemented correctly?

Comment: Are you using Interactors in the project?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant by _UseCase_.

Comment: I would do as follows. Create a composite UseCase that consists of  a UseCase for getting Payments and UseCase for getting Users by Ids residing in Payments retrieved through the 1st UseCase. By doing that your Presenter depends on the composite UseCase only.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but when you create Use Cases, you should be thinking about business transactions, not CRUD methods. So in your suggestion, we have 3 use cases, 2 of them can never be used by any other Presenter or use case and are likely to become useless if, for example, the API response is modified. I'm starting to think that the root of the problem is the repository pattern itself.

Answer (score 2):

As to my understanding SRP does NOT say that each repository should only handle its own entity - instead each repository should only have "a single reason to be changed".

The pattern that should solve your problem is the "unit of work" pattern: just create a "unit of work" repository which exactly handles this query.

In fact in his book "clean architecture" uncle blob states that repository interfaces should be designed in a way being convenient to its user. It should have one method "per query" the use case would raise against the repository.